# Classpath format for Windows command line

Tags: java, command-line, classpath

Haven't used the Windows command line in an age. Could someone please tell me how to get this to work if the files where all on my desktop. Thanks! Also I'm confused about `<class-path>` do I put the path in there or get rid of the `<>`?

```
java -cp < class-path > peersim.Simulator example1.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of the class path is ".", meaning that only the current directory is searched. You can append jar names required by your application by separated with a semi colon (;). Here is an example of running application using classpath, where abc.jar and xyz.jar are required jars.

```
java -classpath .;abc.jar;xyz.jar peersim.Simulator example1.txt
```

Comment: Sorry about the wait there were a lot of libraries in there! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
java -classpath .;myjar.jar;lib/referenced-class.jar my.package.MainClass
```

There is no need for <> brackets.

For your application:

```
java -classpath .;myjar.jar;lib/referenced-class.jar peersim.Simulator example1.txt
```

If your application uses classes from myjar and others